# Vue.js Routing shows 404 error message briefly before redirect after auth check

Tags: vue.js, routes, nuxt.js, http-status-code-404

I have followed a number of posts' guidance on Stack Overflow and other websites about setting up Vue routes to check for user authentication. The setup I now have does essentially work correctly (for each route, the user authentication status is checked, and redirected to the login page if necessary) but there is a small issue in that just before the user is redirected, the standard Nuxt/Vue 404 page screen flashes up momentarily.

This is an example of each route that requires user authentication that I have in router.js:

```js
...
{
    path: '/question/:id/comments',
    name: 'comments',
    component: page('Comments.vue'),
    meta: {requiresAuth: true},
    beforeEnter: (to, from, next) => {
        guard(to, from, next);
    }
},
...
```

And here is my `guard()` function that checks the user authentication and then redirects them with `next()` as required:

```js
const guard = function(to, from, next) {
    axios.get(process.env.apiUrl + 'check-auth').then(response => {
        if( to.matched.some( record => record.meta.requiresAdmin ) ) {
            if( response.data.is_moderator !== 1 ) {
                next({  path: '/' });
            } else {
                next();
            }
        } else if( to.matched.some( record => record.meta.requiresAuth ) ) {
            if( !response.data.id ) {
                next({
                    path: '/login',
                    params: { nextUrl: to.fullPath }
                });
            } else {
                next();
            }
        } else {
            next();
        }

    });
};
```

Many articles online suggested using `localStorage` to check the user authentication but this doesn't work in router.js (presumably because its server side and not client side) but I got around this using a Laravel API call with Axios to check it instead.

If anyone can shed any light on why the 404 screen flashes up first before the redirect? Going to the routes directly works fine, so I am guessing it must be something to do with the `next()` method.

Comment: It is hard to tell from what you provided BUT the object passed into `next()` (or `router.push()`) should not contain combination of `path` and `params` - `params` are allowed only with `name` - check the [note between tho code examples](https://router.vuejs.org/guide/essentials/navigation.html)

Comment: Thanks. I didn't realise that. I did actually use `name` instead of `path` before but had changed it just to see if it would make any difference. The value `nextUrl` param is passed so I know where to send the user after they have logged in.

Comment: You actually make some condition to check if `localStorage` is available, hence nothing is really blocking actually. As of the issue itself, you can actually store the token into cookies (available on both server and client). Try maybe to clean your logic, there a lot of `if/else` even tho I'm not sure it is the actual to the flashing. The issue is probably lying somewhere else, more on your `target` and `ssr` configuration and the way you do access your page. So yeah, a [repro] will be more than useful here because we're lacking details and it can be because of various things.

Comment: I stripped out the axios call and any auth checking and just included the `next()` call in my `guard()` method for all routes, to forward to the login route. If I visit one of the routes that uses beforeEnter, it redirects to the /login URL but shows the 404 page. However, if you refresh the page, it loads. Very odd.

Comment: Yep, [repro] all day. Impossible to help with just this.